# Django translation makemessage error

Tags: python, django

I'm creating django multilingual website.

Settings.py

```
USE_I18N = True

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
            ],
        },
    },
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

]
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('de', _('German')),
)
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
```

template:

```
<h5>{% trans "Hello, this is testing page" %}</h5>
```

urls:

```
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

from django.conf.urls import  include, url

    urlpatterns  = [
      url(r'^rev/', rev, name="rev"),
      url(r'^userprofile/', userprofile, name="profile"),
]
```

views:

```
@login_required
def rev(request):
  return render_to_response('rev.html', {'client': request.user.client, 'user': request.user})

@login_required
@require_http_methods(["GET"])
def userprofile(request):
  return render(request, 'userprofile.html', {
    'user': request.user, 
    'form': UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
  })
```

So, using python makemessage -l de  command I got next error:

```
CommandError: errors happened while running msguniq
msguniq: \u041d\u0435\u0432\u043e\u0437\u043c\u043e\u0436\u043d\u043e \u043f\u0440\u0435\u043e\u0431\u0440\u0430\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0438\u0437 \xabASCII\xbb \u0432 \xabUTF-8\xbb.  msguniq \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0430\u0433\u0430\u0435\u0442\u0441\u044f \u043d\u0430 iconv(). \u042d\u0442\u0430 \u0432\u0435\u0440\u0441\u0438\u044f \u0431\u044b\u043b\u0430 \u0441\u043e\u0431\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0430 \u0431\u0435\u0437 iconv().
```

I think, that I set urls incorrect. All answers about it are at least 3-4 years old, on newest django version , setting urlpatterns = i18n_patterns[....] causes error:

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

GNU gettext installed.

Why Am I really getting this error, and I know, that it is forbidden here to advice anything:) Does anyone have working example with connecting JS (language buttons on website or something) with django translations.

Comment: What version of gettext? Linux or Windows? Run makemessages with -v3 and paste errors. The `TypeError` is not related to this and happens because you are subscripting function as a list. Use `i18n_patterns()`, not `i18n_patterns[]`.

Comment: I'm using newest gettext - 0.19.8. Os - Mac. About -v3: It crashes on processing views.py.  Btw, thanks for reply.

Comment: Then there is something in your views.py that cannot be processed.

Comment: Yep. If it is possible, I'll take few more minutes from your time). Should I add anything to methods(views)/classes(models) (saw an example with method like: def test(self) instead of test(request) and activate('en')   if I want to make multilingual website, cause it works fine with only one language(english)?

Comment: Not usually. If you use Django's [set_language()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#django.views.i18n.set_language) view, then this will set selected language and you don't have to do anything else. Example from documentation will query available languages and create select box with language options. But you can also activate language for the current thread only with `activate()` or manually set language for current session by settings LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This problem appears because of 2 GNU Gettext installed (different version) 1 was already installed another I've installed by myself. Setting path in PyCharm(yes, my django project is in PyCharm) to newest gnu gettext in terminal solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]
```

`LocaleMiddleware` must add between `SessionMiddleware` and `CommonMiddleware`.